# Animate: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, animation

I create anim folder and xml file(scale_wave.xml) and add this code

```
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:duration="100" android:fromalpha="0.0" android:toalpha="1.0">
<scale android:duration="200" android:fromxscale="0.5" android:fromyscale="0.5" android:pivotx="50%" android:pivoty="50%" android:toxscale="1.5" android:toyscale="1.5">
<scale android:duration="100" android:fromxscale="1.5" android:fromyscale="1.5" android:pivotx="50%" android:pivoty="50%" android:startoffset="200" android:toxscale="1.0" android:toyscale="1.0">
```

but i have some error Like this:

- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toalpha' in package 'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromalpha' in package 'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toyscale' in package 'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'pivoty' in package 'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromxscale' in package  'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toxscale' in package 'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'pivotx' in package 'android'

i download listviewanimationdemo from this address: github.com/karnshah8890/tech_andy and import it to eclpise! there is no error in this project and xml file but i have error in my project!

Comment: Please post the xml code here

Comment: Seems names are invalid in Your xml - e.g. fromalpha should be fromAlpha (with capital A as per naming conventions and android documentation - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one, `fromalpha` is not the same as `fromAlpha`. It has case sensitive. Change like that.

`toalpha` -> `toAlpha`

`fromxscale`  -> `fromXScale`,

`toyscale`  -> `toYScale`,

`pivotx`  -> `pivotX`,

use this xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5" />

    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

Comment: toyscale and etc. should be changed also. Almost every animation attribute contains error in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<alpha android:duration="100" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0">
```

Its all case sensitive, so `toalpha` is not the same as `toAlpha`, and `fromalpha` is not the same as `fromAlpha`.

Edit: On a closer look, it seems like most of your other properties are in the wrong case too. Look at [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View) to find the correct name of each property.

Comment: i download listviewanimationdemo from this address:
https://github.com/karnshah8890/tech_andy
 and import it to eclpise! there is no error in this project and xml file but i have error in my project!

Comment: @SiavashA On the contrary, the [corresponding file](https://github.com/karnshah8890/tech_andy/blob/master/ListviewAnimationDemo/res/anim/wave_scale.xml) in the project is perfectly typed out

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:duration="100" android:fromalpha="0.0" android:toalpha="1.0">
<scale android:duration="200" android:fromxscale="0.5" android:fromyscale="0.5" 
android:pivotx="50%" android:pivoty="50%" android:toxscale="1.5" 
android:toyscale="1.5">
<scale android:duration="100" android:fromxscale="1.5" android:fromyscale="1.5" 
android:pivotx="50%" android:pivoty="50%" android:startoffset="200" 
android:toxscale="1.0" android:toyscale="1.0">
```

instead of interpolator use shareInterpolator

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.